# Javascript Code in Nightwatch

Tags: testing, automated-tests

I want to write some javascript code in nightwatch. I know that it need to call .execute() function but I want to separate into different file and calls from main file.

Please help me on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this.

**test.js**

```
module.exports = 'alert("Hello")'
```

**main.js**

```
const test = require('./test.js')
module.exports = {
    'Test' : function (browser) {
        browser
        .url('https://google.com')
        .execute(test)
    }
}
```